# open link search then close javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to open links, what i found, in a new window, then search for a text, and then close the new window.
But its not working, the new window not closed, and the search also not working. and just open the first window.

```
 links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.href.indexOf("jooble") !== -1) {
        var newWindow = window.open(links[i].href);
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("5s")
         if (
                (newWindow.document.documentElement.textContent || newWindow.document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('Jófogás') > -1) {
            console.log("Jófogás")
             
}   if(newWindow){
        newWindow.close();
    }
}, 5000);
                                            }
                                                }`
```

Comment: Why would you expect to have access to the contents of the window you opened? If I make your browser open `yourbank.com` with `window.open`, my script should _under no circumstances_ be able to see what's going on in that page.

Comment: Are you tying to scrap with Javascript in the browser?

Comment: i have thousand urls, and i just want to check which one contain a text.

Comment: So i cant serarch on the opened window?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you cant's access to a `window.open` html contents.

```
var mywindow = window.open('https://www.wikipedia.org/', 'title', 'height=500, width=500'); 
console.log(mywindow.document) //you will get an empty html tag
```

You have to use a `Web Scraper library` like `puppeteer` for that

Answer (score -1):

You not creating variable that your problem, place let before links and try again

```
let links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.href.indexOf("jooble") !== -1) {
        var newWindow = window.open(links[i].href);
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("5s")
         if (
                (newWindow.document.documentElement.textContent || newWindow.document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('Jófogás') > -1) {
            console.log("Jófogás")
             
}   if(newWindow){
        newWindow.close();
    }
}, 5000);
                                        }
                                            }
```